# Finding integration of $\exp(2\overline z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let $C$ denote the unit circle in the complex plane. Find the line integral of $\exp(2\overline z)$ over $C$. I tried to find this integral by using direct definition of contour integral but couldn't work out the whole thing. My attempt:

We denote $C$ in parametric form:$\exp(it)$ $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$

By the definition of contour integral

$\oint _C$ $\exp(2\overline z) dz$ $=$ $\int_{t=0}^{2\pi} \exp(2\exp(-it)) i\exp(it) dt$
=$\int_{t=0}^{2\pi} \exp(2(\cos t -i \sin t) i\exp(it) dt$
=$\int_{t=0}^{2\pi} i \exp(2(\cos t))  \exp i(t-2\sin t)dt$
=$\int_{t=0}^{2\pi} \exp(2(\cos t))(\cos (t-2\sin t)+i\sin (t-2\sin t) )dt$

How to proceed further?
(I am not pretty good at using latex . Apologies for messy writing)

Comment: Please post your unsuccessful work.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Since $\overline z = 1/z$ on $C$, you can evaluate the integral as $2 \pi i \operatorname {Res}_{z = 0} e^{2/z}$ (or $-2 \pi i \operatorname {Res}_{z = \infty} e^{2/z}$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$e^{2\overline{z}}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2\overline{z})^n}{n!}$$

$$J=\oint_C e^{2\overline{z}}\,dz = \oint_C \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2\overline{z})^n}{n!} \, dz =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n!} \oint_C{\overline{z}^n} \, dz$$

$$\oint_C \overline{z}^n \, dz = \int_0^{2\pi}e^{-i n \theta}\, i\,e^{i\theta}\,d\theta = i \int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(1-n)\theta} \, d\theta=  \left\{ \begin{aligned}2\pi i, & \quad n=1 \\0, & \quad \text{otherwise} \end{aligned} \right.$$

$$J= {2\cdot 2\pi i}=4\pi i.$$

Comment: There is a typo, $dz$ should become $i e^{i \theta} d\theta$.

Comment: Thank you!  Corrected.